# Directx Assimp Wrong Texture Coordinates

Tags: c++, directx, textures, assimp

I'm trying to load a mesh into my directx app. I can successfully load any mesh but texture coordinates are wrong on a side of mesh. (Only a side. The other side's texture is mapped correctly)
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR4J5.png)

Here's my code.

Model.h

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

#include <vector>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>

#include <Importer.hpp>
#include <scene.h>
#include <postprocess.h>

#include "Mesh.h"

using namespace DirectX;

class CModel
{
public:
CModel();
~CModel();

bool Load(HWND hwnd, ID3D11Device* dev, ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon, std::string filename);
void Draw(ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon);

void Close();
private:
ID3D11Device *dev;
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;
std::vector<Mesh> meshes;
string directory;
vector<Texture> textures_loaded;
HWND hwnd;

void processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene);
Mesh processMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene);
vector<Texture> loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType type, string typeName, const aiScene* scene);
string determineTextureType(const aiScene* scene, aiMaterial* mat);
int getTextureIndex(aiString* str);
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* getTextureFromModel(const aiScene* scene, int textureindex);
};
#endif
```

Model.cpp

```
#include "Model.h"



CModel::CModel()
{
}


CModel::~CModel()
{
}

bool CModel::Load(HWND hwnd, ID3D11Device* dev, ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon, 
std::string filename)
{
Assimp::Importer importer;

const aiScene* pScene = importer.ReadFile(filename,
    aiProcess_Triangulate |
    aiProcess_ConvertToLeftHanded |
    aiProcess_FlipUVs);

if (pScene == NULL)
    return false;

this->directory = filename.substr(0, filename.find_last_of('/'));

this->dev = dev;
this->hwnd = hwnd;

processNode(pScene->mRootNode, pScene);

return true;
}

void CModel::processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
{
for (UINT i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
{
    aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
    meshes.push_back(this->processMesh(mesh, scene));
}

for (UINT i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
{
    this->processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
}

}

string textype;

Mesh CModel::processMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene)
{
// Data to fill
vector<VERTEX> vertices;
vector<DWORD> indices;
vector<Texture> textures;

if (mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0)
{
    aiMaterial* mat = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];

    if(textype.empty()) textype = determineTextureType(scene, mat);
}

// Walk through each of the mesh's vertices
for (UINT i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
{
    VERTEX vertex;

    vertex.X = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
    vertex.Y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
    vertex.Z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;

    if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0])
    {
        vertex.TEXX = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
        vertex.TEXY = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
    }
    else
    {
        vertex.TEXX = 0.0f;
        vertex.TEXY = 0.0f;
    }

    vertices.push_back(vertex);
}

for (UINT i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
{
    aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];

    for (UINT j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
        indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
}

if (mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0)
{
    aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];

    vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse", scene);
    textures.insert(textures.end(), diffuseMaps.begin(), diffuseMaps.end());

    //vector<Texture> specularMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
    //textures.insert(textures.end(), specularMaps.begin(), specularMaps.end());
}

return Mesh(dev, vertices, indices, textures);
}

vector<Texture> CModel::loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType 
type, string typeName, const aiScene* scene)
{
vector<Texture> textures;
for (UINT i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++)
{
    aiString str;
    mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);
    // Check if texture was loaded before and if so, continue to next iteration: skip loading a new texture
    bool skip = false;
    for (UINT j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size(); j++)
    {
        if (std::strcmp(textures_loaded[j].path.C_Str(), str.C_Str()) == 0)
        {
            textures.push_back(textures_loaded[j]);
            skip = true; // A texture with the same filepath has already been loaded, continue to next one. (optimization)
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!skip)
    {   // If texture hasn't been loaded already, load it
        HRESULT hr;
        Texture texture;
        if (textype == "embedded compressed texture")
        {
            int textureindex = getTextureIndex(&str);
            texture.texture = getTextureFromModel(scene, textureindex);
        }
        else
        {
            string filename = string(str.C_Str());
            filename = directory + '/' + filename;
            hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev, filename.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, &texture.texture, nullptr);
            if (FAILED(hr))
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Texture couldn't be loaded", "Error!", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        }
        texture.type = typeName;
        texture.path = str;
        textures.push_back(texture);
        this->textures_loaded.push_back(texture);  // Store it as texture loaded for entire model, to ensure we won't unnecesery load duplicate textures.
    }
}
return textures;
}


void CModel::Draw(ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon)
{
for (int i = 0; i < meshes.size(); i++)
{
    meshes[i].Draw(devcon);
}
}

void CModel::Close()
{
for (int i = 0; i < meshes.size(); i++)
{
    meshes[i].Close();
}

dev->Release();
}

string CModel::determineTextureType(const aiScene* scene, aiMaterial* mat)
{
aiString textypeStr;
mat->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &textypeStr);
string textypeteststr = textypeStr.C_Str();
if (textypeteststr == "*0" || textypeteststr == "*1" || textypeteststr == "*2" || textypeteststr == "*3" || textypeteststr == "*4" || textypeteststr == "*5")
{
    if (scene->mTextures[0]->mHeight == 0)
    {
        return "embedded compressed texture";
    }
    else
    {
        return "embedded non-compressed texture";
    }
}
if (textypeteststr.find('.') != string::npos)
{
    return "textures are on disk";
}
}

int CModel::getTextureIndex(aiString* str)
{
string tistr;
tistr = str->C_Str();
tistr = tistr.substr(1);
return stoi(tistr);
}

ID3D11ShaderResourceView * CModel::getTextureFromModel(const aiScene * scene, int textureindex)
{
HRESULT hr;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *texture;

int* size = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&scene->mTextures[textureindex]->mWidth);

hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory(dev, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(scene->mTextures[textureindex]->pcData), *size, nullptr, nullptr, &texture, nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
    MessageBox(hwnd, "Texture couldn't be created from memory!", "Error!", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);

return texture;
}
```

Mesh.h (This is a header only class)

```
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <vector>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>
using namespace DirectX;

struct VERTEX {
FLOAT X, Y, Z;
D3DXCOLOR color;
FLOAT TEXX, TEXY;
};

struct Texture {
string type;
aiString path;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *texture;
};

class Mesh {
public:
vector<VERTEX> vertices;
vector<DWORD> indices;
vector<Texture> textures;
ID3D11Device *dev;

Mesh(ID3D11Device *dev,vector<VERTEX> vertices, vector<DWORD> indices, vector<Texture> textures)
{
    this->vertices = vertices;
    this->indices = indices;
    this->textures = textures;

    this->dev = dev;

    this->setupMesh(dev);
}

void Draw(ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon)
{
    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;

    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &VertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &textures[0].texture);

    devcon->DrawIndexed(indices.size(), 0, 0);
}

void Close()
{
    VertexBuffer->Release();
    IndexBuffer->Release();
}
private:
/*  Render data  */
ID3D11Buffer *VertexBuffer, *IndexBuffer;

/*  Functions    */
// Initializes all the buffer objects/arrays
bool setupMesh(ID3D11Device *dev)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * vertices.size();
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    initData.pSysMem = &vertices[0];

    hr = dev->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &initData, &VertexBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
    ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * indices.size();
    ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ibd.MiscFlags = 0;

    initData.pSysMem = &indices[0];

    hr = dev->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &initData, &IndexBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;
}
};

#endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: You loader-code looks ok. Have you opened the model with the appviewer as well? How do the texture coodinates look there?

Comment: Yes I have and it shows it correctly. Some models also renders correctly in this code but some are not(some parts of their texture mapping is not correct.) Thank you so much for trying to help me :)

Comment: Maybe wrong indices? Are there any node inside? Hard to see the error here. You can generate an issue on our github-page.

Comment: Ok. I will generate an issue on your github-page but This is code works perfectly without any error when I use this code itself in OpenGL.

Comment: Also when I use aiProcess_ConvertToLeftHanded flag it makes the wrong side of the mesh correctly mapped and the other side wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. If anyone else facing this issue be sure you have set a SamplerState.